# Trying to Update Python 3 Using Homebrew

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

'''
(base) Kiefer's Macbook Pro:~ kiefergallant$ brew upgrade python3
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man8

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man8

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man8
(base) Kiefer's Macbook Pro:~ kiefergallant$ 
'''

Having a hard time updating python3 so I can use Tkinter

Comment: What I did was install different versions of Python due to project requirements. I have projects that use 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7. A dirty approach but I just delete versions of python I no longer use (e.g. v3.5).

Comment: Have you done what the message tells you to do?